Determine maximum score, the names scorers, and days
We maintain team score per member for each day. How do I capture the maximum score for any day of the month, the names of the members who achieved the maximum score, and also the days when it was achieved?
Data



Name
1-Dec
2-Dec
3-Dec
4-Dec
5-Dec
6-Dec
7-Dec
8-Dec
9-Dec
10-Dec




Name1
30
25
40
40








Name2
40
45
60
55








Name3
25
40
30
30








Name4
50
45
50
60








Max value
50
45
60










Max value of any day - 60   of  Name2, Name4 on 3rd Dec, 4 Dec

Spreadsheet

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Please [edit] your question and insert a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results.

Use filter(), byrow() and bycol(), like this:
=max(B2:5)

=join(", ", filter( 
  A2:A5, 
  D9 = byrow(B2:ZZZ5, lambda(row, max(row))) 
))

=join(", ", filter( 
  B1:ZZZ1, 
  D9 = bycol(B2:ZZZ5, lambda(col, max(col))) 
))

See
filter(),
byrow() and
bycol().
